# jQuery file upload plugin: Different containers for upload/download templates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin for multiple file upload. I've adapted it for Zurbs Foundation Framework, added database connection and sorting of the uploaded images via drag and drop.

Basically everything's working fine, but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to render the upload and download templates to different dom elements, so that I can use for example a modal for the preview?

There is an option "[filesContainer](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#filescontainer)", but it is used for both the upland and the download template.

Any help or idea to point me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find this out?

Comment: Seems like there is no still solution for this case :(